# software-properties-gtk no working

Tags: 14.04, python, gtk

Hi Guys i am a newbie at Ubuntu and am having a problem... i managed to get everything working like a dream including, unfortunately after my latest upgrade/update, my software-properties-gtk application stopped functioning. when i try start it in the gui it simply does not respond and when i try run it in the terminal i get this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 51, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import ppa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 25, in <module>
    import json
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 5, in <module>
    from json import scanner
ImportError: cannot import name 'scanner'
```

Please could anybody help me? I am at a total loss?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

`scanner.py` should be in the same directory as `decoder.py`, both in `/usr/lib/python3.4/json/`.

As it's hard to find out why the file got deleted/moved I'd suggest to reinstall `libpython3.4-stdlib`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.4-stdlib
```

Comment: Thanx Sylvain I really appreciate the help. That did the trick.